# How to present a second screen of the same scene in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, directx

I have a Windows application that uses directX and open a Windows.Form to shows vrml objects in 3D space.
I want to open a second screen that will show
the exact same scene but from different angle.
(Like Rear-view mirror in car racing games)
I've looked into MDI but I just can't get my head around it.
Any instruction will be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: I haven't try it but did you try a second form?

Comment: I Manged to open another blank window, but my goal here is that window will show the same scene as the main window just from a different angle. I couldn't figure out what to connect to what to make this happened...

Comment: You can add your second form like this: `Form2 frm2 = new Form2(); frm2.TopLevel = false; this.Controls.Add( frm2 ); frm2.Visible = true;` and in your `Form2` initialize directx and draw. I don't know if you can have two directx initializations in the same app though. You can try.

Comment: The two forms can communicate with each other. When you present to one send info to the second and present there two.

Comment: Now I am thinking about it you can create two seperate directx resourses and point them to two different controls in your form. Can you post code how you initialize directx and draw?